# Error: A value of type 'Future<Widget>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Widget' flutter

Tags: flutter

i get this error when i want to show the qrcode generated by this method.
I have to generate this qrcode and then show it on the screen, but I find a compilation error. I come from Swift and it is not clear to me all about how to build a view

```
  Future<Widget> buildQrCode() async {
Map<String,dynamic> myData = {
  'type': 1,
  'content': name,
  'mac' : await Utilities.getDeviceMac(),
};

String encodedJson = jsonEncode(myData);
QrCodeEncrypter.encrypt(password, myData);

return QrImage(
  data: encodedJson,
  size: 320,
  gapless: false,
);
```

}

here is where I call the method to show the image on the screen:

```
      @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    _buttonHeight = size.height * .05;

    double splitPoint = size.height / 7;

    return FutureBuilder<UserData>(
        future: contentManager.getUserData(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<UserData> snapUserData) {
          if (snapUserData.hasError)
            return Container(
              child: Center(
                child: Text("There was some error"),
              ),
            );
          if (snapUserData.connectionState != ConnectionState.done)
            return Container(
              child: Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ),
            );
          return Stack(
            alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
            children: [
              // SFONDO
              Positioned(
                bottom: 0,
                child: Container(
                  height: size.height,
                  width: size.width,
                  color: appColors.primaryColor,
                ),
              ),
              // TITOLO
              Positioned(
                top: size.height * .05,
                child: Text(
                  localization.showQR,
                  style: Theme.of(context).primaryTextTheme.headline5.copyWith(
                        color: appColors.green,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                ),
              ),
              buildQrCode(),
              Positioned(
                bottom: size.height * .18,
                width: size.width * .8,
                child: AutoSizeText(
                  localization.home_subLabel,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  maxLines: 1,
                  style: Theme.of(context).primaryTextTheme.headline5.copyWith(
                        color: appColors.green,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                bottom: size.height * .08,
                width: size.width * .7,
                height: size.height * .05,
                  child: TextField(
                    inputFormatters: [
                      new LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(11),
                    ],
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      filled: true,
                      fillColor: Colors.white,
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                      enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 18.0,
                          //height: 2.0,
                          color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                  ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: Stack expects a Widget but your method returns a Future<widgets>, you need to use FutureBuilder to build that widget rather than directly calling that method.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like (Suggesting a simple edit)

```
///Define A state Variable
bool isQrImgReady = false;

Future<Widget> buildQrCode() async {
Map<String,dynamic> myData = {
  'type': 1,
  'content': name,
  'mac' : await Utilities.getDeviceMac(),
};
String encodedJson = jsonEncode(myData);
QrCodeEncrypter.encrypt(password, myData);

///Change state variable to True when its ready
setState((){
  isQrImgReady = true;
});

return QrImage(
  data: encodedJson,
  size: 320,
  gapless: false,
);
```

Then

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    _buttonHeight = size.height * .05;

    double splitPoint = size.height / 7;

    return FutureBuilder<UserData>(
        future: contentManager.getUserData(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<UserData> snapUserData) {
          if (snapUserData.hasError)
            return Container(
              child: Center(
                child: Text("There was some error"),
              ),
            );
          if (snapUserData.connectionState != ConnectionState.done)
            return Container(
              child: Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ),
            );
          return Stack(
            alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
            children: [
              // SFONDO
              Positioned(
                bottom: 0,
                child: Container(
                  height: size.height,
                  width: size.width,
                  color: appColors.primaryColor,
                ),
              ),
              // TITOLO
              Positioned(
                top: size.height * .05,
                child: Text(
                  localization.showQR,
                  style: Theme.of(context).primaryTextTheme.headline5.copyWith(
                        color: appColors.green,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                ),
              ),

              ///Check if Widget is ready or not
              this.isQrImgReady 
              ? buildQrCode() 
              : SizedBox(),

              Positioned(
                bottom: size.height * .18,
                width: size.width * .8,
                child: AutoSizeText(
                  localization.home_subLabel,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  maxLines: 1,
                  style: Theme.of(context).primaryTextTheme.headline5.copyWith(
                        color: appColors.green,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                bottom: size.height * .08,
                width: size.width * .7,
                height: size.height * .05,
                  child: TextField(
                    inputFormatters: [
                      new LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(11),
                    ],
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      filled: true,
                      fillColor: Colors.white,
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                      enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 18.0,
                          //height: 2.0,
                          color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                  ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: now it compiles, but it remains empty and the image never arrives. I had to enter "await" in       'mac' : await Utilities.getDeviceMac(),
because otherwise I don't know how to get the data I need. in the other parts of the project it is written like this. but if I remove await it manages to generate the image for me

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are not calling buildQrCode asynchronously as you are not using the await keyword, and you cannot make the builder function async.

So a proper way to do that is to declare a widget variable in your StatefulWidget that will hold the buildQrCode initially using the initState then put that widget in your stack. As follows :

```
Widget qrCodeHolder ;

void initState() {
  super.initState() ;
  setQrCodeHolder();
}

setQrCodeHolder() async {
  var tmp = await buildQrCode() ; 
  setState (() {
    qrCodeHolder = tmp ; 
  }); 
}
```

and then in your stack you swap your builQrCode with qrCodeHolder.

Comment: now it compiles, but it remains empty and the image never arrives. I had to enter "await" in 'mac' : await Utilities.getDeviceMac(), because otherwise I don't know how to get the data I need. in the other parts of the project it is written like this. but if I remove await it manages to generate the image for me